# How can i changes the values in a nested list to those specified in a dict?

Tags: python

I have this code in which I have a list of lists and inside the sub-lists we got numbers. However, I also have a dict storing key-value pairs of name-number, in which the number is the index of the name stored in another list, but I want to replace all the numbers in the nested list with their respective names. Instead of having [1,9,13] I want to have ['The Beach Chimney', 'Parlay', 'The Private Exhibit'].

```
out = [(ind,ind2) for ind,i in enumerate(rows) 
                  for ind2,y in enumerate(i) if y == '1']

list_of_restaurants_index = []
for empty_list in range(100):
  empty_list = []
  list_of_restaurants_index.append(empty_list)

for i in out:
  for empty_list in list_of_restaurants_index:
    if i[0] == list_of_restaurants_index.index(empty_list):
      empty_list.append(i[1])
print(list_of_restaurants_index)

restaurants_dict = {}
for i in header:
  restaurants_dict[i] = header.index(i)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 9, 13], [8, 14, 17], [6, 14], [4, 8, 9, 12], [1, 2, 5, 6, 12, 13, 18], [1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12], [1, 12, 14, 16], [3, 4, 5, 13, 14, 17, 18], [4, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 18], [3, 16], [1, 3, 5, 10, 13], [1, 5, 10, 15, 17], [2, 4, 6, 7, 10, 13], [2, 4, 9, 12], [9, 11, 12, 13], [1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 17], [6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 18], [2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 13], [4, 7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18], [7, 12, 16, 17, 18], [3, 7, 10, 13, 14], [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 14, 17, 18], [8, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 17], [1, 4, 7, 9, 13, 16], [4, 10, 12, 14, 15], [2, 3, 4, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17], [1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 16], [5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6], [10, 16, 18], [6, 13, 14, 17], [1, 6, 16, 17], [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 12, 15, 18], [3, 4, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18], [1, 2, 6, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 5, 10, 13, 18], [4, 5, 13, 18], [5, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 15, 17], [2, 14], [4, 5, 9, 11, 12, 14], [1, 3, 5, 10, 11, 15], [3, 12, 13, 16], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 15], [4, 6, 9, 13, 15, 16, 18], [2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 15], [1, 7, 12, 14, 17], [5, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15, 18], [2], [2], [4, 5, 7, 11, 12, 14], [1, 4, 9, 14, 18], [3, 6, 8, 15, 18], [1, 4, 7, 8, 14], [3, 4, 7, 11, 15], [1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18], [2], [2], [5, 6, 8, 14, 15, 16, 18], [6], [8, 10, 12, 16], [1, 4, 5, 10, 14, 17, 18], [6], [5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14], [1, 11, 12, 17], [1, 5, 10, 14, 15], [3, 4, 6, 9, 10, 15, 18], [4, 8, 10, 16, 17, 18], [4, 7, 14, 17], [1, 2, 3, 9, 16], [10, 12, 14, 16], [1, 2, 8, 10, 15], [1, 2, 4, 10, 13, 17], [3, 7, 17], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 11, 12, 17], [1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 16], [1, 2, 4, 8, 13], [8, 11], [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 18], [1, 4, 5, 11, 12, 14, 17], [5, 8, 9, 14], [2], [4, 5, 7, 10, 14, 16], [6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 13, 14], [7, 12, 14], [3, 4, 7, 11, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15], [2], [6], [5, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18], [3, 4, 5, 11, 12, 13], [3, 5, 6, 14, 17, 18], [9, 12, 13, 15], [4, 14, 15, 16, 18], [4, 8], [3], [3]]
```

Also, here's what the dict is storing:

```
{'': 0, 'The Beach Chimney': 1, "The Pirate's Harvest": 2, 'The Square Dragon': 3, 'The Spicy Trumpet': 4, 'Vertigo': 5, 'Drifters': 6, 'The Tulip': 7, 'Seawise': 8, 'Parlay': 9, 'The Modern Salmon': 10, 'The Bitter Windmill': 11, 'The Minty Window': 12, 'The Private Exhibit': 13, 'Enigma': 14, 'The Lighthouse': 15, 'Harlequin': 16, 'Midnight': 17, 'Gastrognome': 18}
```

obs: header is a list containing the names.

Comment: Assuming header is the dictionary, have you tried `empty_list.append(header[i[1] - 1])`

Comment: Hey! Sorry, header is actually the list containing the names of the restaurants. restaurant_dict is the dictionary, I'll edit the question, mb.

Comment: Also, the shown dict seems backwards? Did you want `1: 'The Beach Chimney'`? That way, you can convert a list of `[1]` to `['The Beach Chimney']`?

Comment: Oh should I have the number as the key then?

Comment: If `header` is a list of strings, and `'The Beach Chimney'` is at element 1, and `empty_list.append(i[1])` is appending `1` to the first list, then you want what I put in the first comment

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked just fine lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the purpose of the dict.

`empty_list.append(i[1])` seems to be appending a number

That number happens to align with the indicies of the strings you want.

Therefore, you could instead use

```
name = header[i[1]]
empty_list.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having trouble making out where you are starting from, but starting from your output of the list of integers and the dict at the end of your question, you could do this:

```
inverted_dict = {restaurants_dict[k]:k for k in restaurants_dict}

rest_names = []
for i in range(len(list_of_restaurants_index)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(list_of_restaurants_index[i])):
        row.append(inverted_dict[list_of_restaurants_index[i][j]])
    rest_names.append(row)
```

"rest_names" should be what you want, I think.
This creates a new list, rather than editing the members of your original list.  Not sure if that matters to you.